# Q: Proper way to access data in a data only dll file

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

My application store some data in data only dll files. Those dll files are loaded with LoadLibrary() when needed at runtime and then discarded with FreeLibrary() after finish using them. The main application access the data stored in the dll files using GetProcAddress(). The program is written in C++ and uses WinAPI calls, no MFC or other libraries. It has two versions x64 and x86. It works fine on most systems. My dll files do not call other libraries or depend on anything else. Each is a stand alone file.

Recently, I discovered the program does not work on one machine. this specific one has Windows 10 x64 installed on it. After investigations I found the following:

1. LoadLibrary() fails with error message "Could not find module". The dll is in same directory with main program.
2. I replaced the call to LoadLibrary() with LoadLibraryEx() and tried the following falgs:

   1. LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL did not work. The dll could not be loaded.
   2. DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES ... works?? But, Microsoft strongly recommends not to use it.
   3. LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE ... loading the dll succeeds?? But, the call to GetProcessAddress later fails. the program could not access the data in the dll file. So this is not actually working.
3. I could not find anything wrong with this machine. All other programs are working fine.
4. I tried the x86 version on this machine and it worked fine using original LoadLibrary().
5. My installer is dual system and automatically installs x64 version when it finds x64 windows. Normal user can not simply switch to x86 when he gets such error.
6. My question is how can I eliminate this error and make my program works on any machine:

   1. Should I call LoadLibraryEx() using DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES flag and ignore Microsoft warning?
   2. Is there any way I can get my library loaded with simple call to LoadLibrary()?
   3. If I call LoadLibraryEx() with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE flag, as recommended by Microsoft, how can I access the data without calling GetProcessAddress()?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does dependency walker say about the x64 DLL on that specific machine?

Comment: Also, why are you calling `GetProcAddress` if you say the DLL is "data only"?

Comment: 1. I tried dependency walker on both x64 and x86 versions of the dll. both produced too many errors on a system when the program works fine and have no problems at all. All are "Error opening file. The system can not find the file specified. I could not get any help out of this program.

Comment: Fine, use the modern [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/) instead.

Comment: 2. I call GetProcAddress to get access to the variables defined in the dll as follows: auto Count = (int *) GetProcAddress (ElemLib,"ElemCount") ; or auto Prop = (float **) GetProcAddress (ElemLib,"ElemProp") ; where ElemLib is the handle returned by LoadLibrary() function. ElemCount is array of int and ElemProp is 2D array of float

Comment: Is your application consistent with the DLL version? Is the character encoding in your `LoadLibrary` correct, for "Could not find module", have you try to hard code the path in `LoadLibrary` to see if it work? Maybe someone is using `SetDllDirectory("")` to delete the current path? You'd better provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)